# Prettier agrega barras en las etiquetas sin contenido

Tags: html, vscode

Muchas gracias de antemano a quién pueda responder, Tengo la extensión de prettier en el vs code y cuando estoy formateando HTML me agrega la diagonal "/" al final de las etiquetas: meta, link y otras que no tienen contenido, no he podido dar con la configuración correcta para que no cierre esas etiquetas con la barra, hasta he tratado con el json pero hubo una configuración que no recuerdo de dónde saqué que al pasar el cursos por encima me decía que era una configuración invalida
Un ejemplo de cómo se ve formateado con Prettier

```
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="" />
```

Y así cómo debería verse

```
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="">
```

Ciertamente una opción sería no usar prettier, pero por otro lado al ser una extensión popular según lo que sé, sé que usar esa "/" al final es una mala práctica para el HTML otro ejemplo de eso puede ser la etiqueta`<br>` que aunque no se usa prettier la formatea con la barra

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: Gracias! ya me  he pasado por allí  :D

Comment: Si desactivas esa extension deja de pasar?? el tema de las extensiones es todo un tema en si.. tal vez es un conjunto de ellas que provoca eso...

Comment: No soy mucho de extensiones, pero por lo menos esta me la vi bastante elegante, a ver. La cosa es: Cuando formateas con HTML vanilla solamente te identa el código y agrega unos cuantos saltos de línea, pero cuando habilito prettier agrega esta barra al final de esas etiquetas que según lo que estaba leyendo no es buena práctica, entonces pensando que es una configuración estuve buscando por el sitio de prettier y preguntando en chat GPT y allí me arroja que cree un archivo .prettierrc en la raiz del archivo y agregue una línea de configuración:  "htmlWhitespaceSensitivity": "ignore" pero nada

Comment: He intentado ya un par de otras cosas, la mayoría de respuestas que me arroja el software de I.A. pero quería saber si a alguien más le sucede esto y cómo se configura, y respondiendo a tu comentario, si deja de pasar porque toma el formateo default de vscode para html

Comment: Y todo eso que intentaste, no lo agregaste a tu pregunta porque???.. mira si te contestaban exactamente lo mismo, ibas a tener el mismo problema ;)

Comment: @Cris223511.dev no es lo que esta preguntando... dice que prettier le agrega una barra que no quiere...

Comment: @gbianchi caramba, cierto!

Comment: @Cris223511.dev Así es mi compa pero la pregunta es otra :D

Comment: si esto: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60593290/visual-studio-code-1-42-is-changing-br-to-br-on-format no ayudo, estas seguro que no es la configuracion por defecto???? prettier es como es... y si todos votaron por poner las barras, las va a poner...

Comment: @gbianchi he sido iluminado, puedo concluir el hilo, ciertamente la barra es opcional (debe ser cosa simplemente de prettier), estuve buscando información detallada y la encontré acá: https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/syntax.html#start-tags punto Nro 6